# React синтаксис

Tags: javascript, reactjs

изучаю react, есть код

```js
const {article} = this.props;
```

Что такое this.props я понимаю, а вот конструкцию {article} нет
и хотел бы знать что будет значить вот такая запись

```js
const {article, article2} = this.props;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это называется [деструктуризацией](https://learn.javascript.ru/destructuring).

Ваши примеры эквивалентны следующим:

```
const article = this.props.article;
const article2 = this.props.article2;
```